# if slope is greater than some threshold, then color the line red in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graphing

I have a line graph that I'm plotting in python. The last thing that I need to do is add a line telling it to color a section of the graph red if the slope is greater that 25. How would I do this?

Here's what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('ReactorStartupTemps.csv')
print(data)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 4]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.xlabel('Time [min]', fontdict={'fontname': 'Times New Roman', 
'style': 'italic'})
plt.ylabel('Temperature [C]', fontdict={'fontname': 'Times New Roman', 
'style': 'italic'})
plt.title('Reactor Startup Temperatures', fontdict={'fontname': 'Times 
New Roman', 'style': 'italic'})

[slope, intercept] = np.polyfit(data.Time, data.Temp, 1)
if slope > 25:
    plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp, color="red", linewidth=1.5)
else:
    plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp, color="black", linewidth=1.5)

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major', color='grey', linewidth=.8)
plt.grid(which='minor', color='lightgrey', linewidth=.4, ls='--')

plt.show()
```

What the graph needs to look like:

[image]

Graph as of now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using the slope of the regression line. [`np.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) performs least squares and returns the slope of the fitted line, which is not what you want.

Instead you're looking for the slope between all consecutive points:

- Use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to compute `(y2-y1) / (x2-x1)` for all consecutive points
- Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to mask the segments where the slope exceeds 25
- Use a high `zorder` to raise the masked segments

```
THRESHOLD = 25

slopes = data.Temp.diff() / data.Time.diff()
plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp, color='k')
plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp.where(slopes > THRESHOLD), color='r', zorder=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('ReactorStartupTemps.csv')
print(data)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7, 5]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.xlabel('Time [min]', fontdict = {'fontname': 'Times New Roman', 
'style': 'italic'})
plt.ylabel('Temperature [C]', fontdict = {'fontname': 'Times New 
Roman', 
'style': 'italic'})
plt.title('Reactor Startup Temperatures', fontdict = {'fontname': 
'Times 
New Roman', 'style': 'italic'})    
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(np.log(data.Time), np.log(data.Temp), 1)
if slope > 25 :
    plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp, color = "red",linewidth = 1.5)
else:
    plt.plot(data.Time, data.Temp, color = "black",linewidth = 1.5)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which = 'major', color = 'grey', linewidth = .8)
plt.grid(which = 'minor', color = 'lightgrey', linewidth = .4, ls = 
'--')

plt.show()
```

first you have to calculate slope and then you can implement your condition

for slope calculation

```
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(np.log(data.Time), np.log(data.Temp), 1)
```

Comment: I tried that and I am now getting the error "Too many values to unpack"

Comment: I put slope, intercept in brackets --> [slope, intercept]. This got rid of the error but still isn't turning the graph red